# What .NET Framework to use?

Tags: .net

I am creating an application using Visual Basic (.NET). When I have to distribute the application I also needs to pack the appropriate .NET framework to the end-users. This increases the size of the package and also takes a lot of time installing the .NET framework. I like to avoid this.

Is there a .NET framework that is available by default on all Windows versions from **XP** to **8.1**, so I only have to distribute the application without .NET framework?

Comment: May be you should look into this wikipedia page, which explains what is available and where http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no single version of .NET available by default on every version of windows.  As for XP, it's no longer supported by Microsoft, and the .NET framework has not supported it since 4.5, so if you plan to target XP you cannot use .NET 4.5 or greater, you must use 4.0 or older.  However, 4.0 only supports XP SP3, it doesn't support SP2 or older, so if you need to support XP SP2 or older then you are stuck with .net 3.5 at most.

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP SP2 contains .Net Framework 2.0 in it. If you use WinForms, you can easily retarget to 2.0.

Comment: It's not just WinForms. ASP.NET and DLLs and other project types should be capable of being targeted for the 2.0 framework.  The only exception to this would be brand new parts of the framework introduced in 3.0+ (WCF, async/await, etc).

Comment: @Tim - as in... almost everything you'd want to use ;)

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch - Yep :)

Comment: @Tim As for TPL and async\await, you can run it on .Net 2.0, more informations is there (http://habrahabr.ru/post/179381/). It's a russian article about porting async+LINQ from mono to .Net 2.0.

Comment: @EldarDordzhiev - I don't read Russian, and personally have no interest in backfitting newer features of .NET to 2.0.  But it might help the OP if they absolutely have to stay on 2.0.